# Can't get deleted items from OpenLDAP Server using Content Synchronization Operation (syncrepl)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ldap, openldap, directoryservices

I set up my OpenLDAP server on a Ubuntu 19.04 VM and allowed replication (using this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-replication). Everything for replication seems ok.
I don't have set up a consumer server as my code will act as one, pulling modified elements regularly.

The modified/added entries are correctly retrieved BUT I want to get deleted items and I can't seem to get it to work.

As described by the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4533#section-3.3.2, I should receive a Sync Info Message Containing an attribute named "syncUUIDs"

> syncUUIDs contain a set of UUIDs of the entries and references that have been deleted from the content since the last Sync Operation

My Sync Request Control initialization

```
syncRequestValue = BerConverter.Encode("{iob}", new object[] { refreshOnly, cookieSrc, true });
testdsrc = new DirectoryControl("1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1", syncRequestValue, true, true);
```

Adding the control to the request and then send it.

```
request.Controls.Add(testdsrc);
connection.SendRequest(request);
response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
```

Getting the Entries, here I deleted 1 entry, modified 1 and added 1, I only get 2 entries (the added/modified ones)

```
entries = response.Entries;
if (response.Entries.Count > 0)
{
    object[] controlvalue = BerConverter.Decode("{Ob}", 
    response.Controls[0].GetValue());
    cookieSrc = (byte[])controlvalue[0];
    var refreshDeletes = (bool)controlvalue[1];
    File.WriteAllBytes(strFileName, cookieSrc);
}
```

Do you know if it comes from the configuration of my LDAP server or my code in C#?

I don't know if :

- my server sends the correct response and the SearchResponse class doesn't know how to interpret it

or

- if my server is misconfigured and doesn't send the list of deleted entries at all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding the "sync" loglevel on my OpenLdap server I was able to see that a Intermediate message with the correct OID was sent.

```
slapd debug  conn=1131 fd=15 ACCEPT from IP=x.x.x.x (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=1 SRCH attr=dn objectClass cn displayName
**slapd debug  conn=1131 op=1 INTERM oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.4**
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=1 ENTRY dn="ou=uni,dc=example,dc=com"
slapd debug  syncprov_search_response: cookie=rid=000,csn=20190924091959.141380Z#000000#000#000000
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slapd debug  conn=1131 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=1131 fd=15 closed
```

By using a Perl script and the Perl Net::LDAP library  I was able to see that the response value contained the UUIDS of the deleted entries.

I know now that my server is correctly configured but I don't know how to get the UUIDs using .NET

```
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAP::Control::SyncRequest;
use Net::LDAP::Intermediate::SyncInfo;
use Net::LDAP::Constant qw(
 LDAP_SYNC_REFRESH_ONLY
 LDAP_SYNC_REFRESH_AND_PERSIST
 LDAP_SUCCESS );
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new( "127.0.0.1:389" ) or die($@);

$req = Net::LDAP::Control::SyncRequest->new( mode => LDAP_SYNC_REFRESH_ONLY, cookie => "rid=000,csn=20190912114502.963050Z#000000#000#000000" );
my $mesg = $ldap->search(base=> 'dc=example,dc=com',
                         scope    => 'sub',
                         control  => [ $req ],
                         callback => \&searchCallback, # call for each entry
                         filter   => "(objectClass=*)",
                         attrs    => [ '*']);

   print "\n==========\n";
   print Dumper($mesg);  


sub searchCallback {
  my $message = shift;
  my $entry = shift;
  my @controls = $message->control;
  print Dumper($message);
  print "\n==========\n";
  my $count = scalar(@controls);
  print "  $count controls in response\n";
  if ( $count == 0 ) {
    if ($message->isa('Net::LDAP::Intermediate::SyncInfo')) {
      print "Received Sync Info message\n";
    }
    return;
  }


  if (!defined($controls[0]) ) {
    print "  control 0 is undefined\n";
    return;
  }

  if ($controls[0]->isa('Net::LDAP::Control::SyncState')) {
    print "Received Sync State Control\n";
    print $entry->dn()."\n";
    #print Dumper($controls[0]->entryUUID);
    print 'State: '.$controls[0]->state."\n  entryUUID: ".$controls[0]->entryUUID."\n  cookie: ".$controls[0]->cookie."\n";
  } elsif ($controls[0]->isa('Net::LDAP::Control::SyncDone')) {
    print "Received Sync Done Control\n";
    print '  Cookie: '.$controls[0]->cookie."\n  refreshDeletes: ".$controls[0]->refreshDeletes."\n";
  } else {
    print Dumper($controls[0]);
  }
}
```

I created a new question asking how to get the Sync Info Message using .Net.