# How to catch LDAP Sync Info Message using Content Synchronization Operation

Tags: c#, .net-core, ldap, openldap, directoryservices

I am trying to retrieve the deleted UUIDs from a Openldap server using a .Net Core Console Application.

I was able to see that a Sync Info Message was indeed sent by my Openldap server and that it contained the UUIDS of the **present** entries by using a Perl script and dumping the whole response.

I set up a Openldap server with the syncprov Overlay (see my previous question [Can't get deleted items from OpenLDAP Server using Content Synchronization Operation (syncrepl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908841/cant-get-deleted-items-from-openldap-server-using-content-synchronization-opera)).

**After re-reading the RFC4533 multiple times and the OpenLdap Syncrepl documentation and analysing the response, with my current configuration (No Accesslog) it is impossible to retrieve deleted entries, only a list of present entries. They are contained in the Sync Info Message. I wish to retrieve the information anyway so I can make a delta between what is sent and what is on my client.**

Do you know how to catch the message in C#?

I tried using the DirectoryServices.Protocols and the Novell.Directory.Ldap libraries (separately). I must have missed something but don't know what exactly...

I used the Novell Code sample (the SearchPersist one and adding the corresponding control) available at https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/edirectory-developer-documentation/ldap-libraries-for-c-sharp/.

I can retrieve added/modified entries but not the Sync Info Message containing the **present** entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By digging a bit into the Novell Library, I found some useful classes for decoding ASN1 Objects.

By using the following code I am able to determine the type of the Intermediate Sync Info Message.

```
var decoder = new LBERDecoder();
(Asn1Tagged)decoder.decode(intermediateResponse.getValue());`
```

Then, depending on the Tag I am able to decode the message (using the method `.decode(valueToDecode)`)